# SVG/D3 - g with embedded svg image not showing up (g is size 0 by 0 and svg image is no where to be seen)

Tags: html, css, svg

I am near the point of rendering an svg with an image (an svg file)

This renders find standalone in Chrome when loaded by itself.

**starlight.svg**

```
<svg width="92" height="88" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" overflow="hidden">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip0"><path d="M81 101 173 101 173 189 81 189Z" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g clip-path="url(#clip0)" transform="translate(-81 -101)">
        <path d="M83.5001 145.5 95.6245 137.347 89.3949 124.5 104.166 123.226 105.5 109.127 118.959 115.073 127.5 103.5 136.041 115.073 149.5 109.127 150.835 123.226 165.605 124.5 159.376 137.347 171.5 145.5 159.376 153.653 165.605 166.5 150.835 167.774 149.5 181.873 136.041 175.927 127.5 187.5 118.959 175.927 105.5 181.873 104.166 167.774 89.3949 166.5 95.6245 153.653Z" stroke="#B4C7E7" stroke-miterlimit="8" fill="#B4C7E7" fill-rule="evenodd"/><path d="M100 145C100 130.641 111.864 119 126.5 119 141.136 119 153 130.641 153 145 153 159.359 141.136 171 126.5 171 111.864 171 100 159.359 100 145Z" fill="#FFFFFF" fill-rule="evenodd"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

In my page I call this svg via an image tag inside of a g and inside an svg tag

How do I render this without having  0 width 0 height g enclosing the img tag in html?

The image below does not appear and g renders with no width and no height.

**snippet of main page**

```
<g width="55px" height="55px" class="star">
     <img width="55" height="55" src="/app/assets/images/starlight.svg" transform="translate(25,25)">
     </img>
</g>
```

Note:  rendering in d3.js directly works perfectly, so I might stick with that method.

```
let star = chart.select('svg g').selectAll('path.star').data([0]);
star = star.enter()
           .append('g')
           .attr('class', 'star')
           .merge(star);

    star.attr("d","M81 101 173 101 173 189 81 189Z")
        .attr("fill-rule","evenodd")
        .attr("clip-rule","evenodd")
        .append('g')
        .attr("clip-path","url(#clip0)")
        .attr("transform","translate(-275 -195)")
        .append('path')
        .attr("d","M83.5001 145 95.6245 136.75 89.3949 123.75 104.166 122.461 105.5 108.194 118.959 114.211 127.5 102.5 136.041 114.211 149.5 108.194 150.835 122.461 165.605 123.75 159.376 136.75 171.5 145 159.376 153.25 165.605 166.25 150.835 167.539 149.5 181.806 136.041 175.789 127.5 187.5 118.959 175.789 105.5 181.806 104.166 167.539 89.3949 166.25 95.6245 153.25Z")
        .attr("stroke","#B4C7E7")
        .attr("stroke-miterlimit","8")
        .attr("fill","#B4C7E7")
        .attr("fill-rule","evenodd")
        .style("opacity", 0.0)
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .style("opacity", 1.0);
star = star
     .append('path')
     .attr("d","M100 144.5C100 129.864 111.864 118 126.5 118 141.136 118 153 129.864 153 144.5 153 159.136 141.136 171 126.5 171 111.864 171 100 159.136 100 144.5Z")
     .attr("fill","#FFFFFF")
     .attr("fill-rule","evenodd").attr("transform","translate(-275 -195)")
     .style("opacity", 0.0)
     .transition()
     .duration(500)
     .style("opacity", 1.0);
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fyv41kaL/7/   example fiddle for d3 that works without embedded image

Comment: I am assuming your path to your .svg image is correct and you tried it with 2 dots before the slash as follows   src="../app/assets/images/starlight.svg" and perhaps by leaving the first slash out.  Sometimes documents can do funny things.

Comment: use svg image tag, you are using html <img> tag      svg image tag:--<image href="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png" height="200" width="200"/>

Comment: Hi again, I have tried your solution without any .js, I tried on my local machine as well put it up on my website.  I also removed the g and added a div, it works in all cases, the svg star image is showing in all cases I mentioned. You must have something else going.  Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Vahe, I have added something else to my answer below.  See if changing svg image path (folder or no folder) will change any outcome.

Comment: Thank you Mugé.   I never knew to try this I will try,  let me wait but it seems the answer provided is the closest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second solution, add the following lines to your .htaccess file and test if the svg image shows:

```
# SHOW SVG IMAGES 
AddType image/svg+xml svg   
AddType image/svg+xml svgz
```

-->  remember to change the folder name from 'image/' to where your image resides.

or use the solution that works in your jsfiddle.

Comment: Thank you, for the quick response Mugé,  I initially attempted to modify my root .htaccess of my project directory and even restarted server which might not have been necessary but I cleared cache/cookies and did a refresh of the page, but I did not see any change.  However, I will give this a go.   Let me wait a bit for some answers to trickle down.  I am awarding you my point for your answer for now.  Thanks again!

Comment: @VaheJabagchourian  Thank you for your kind point.  I hoped it would work for you as well.  Sorry, I just see I did not mark up your question.  I was testing your other solutions.  I like your multi approach.

Answer (score 1):

- `<g>` does not support width/height attributes, it's always the size of its contents.
- SVG does not have an img tag (that's a HTML tag), the tag in SVG is called image and has different properties e.g. href rather than src

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you for the helpful suggestion and info.  I actually did play with the tag name as well but still I did not observe a successful rendered object.    It's so strange.  I have up-voted your answer.   I want to wait for some more answers too it might be benefit others who view the question.